# Asp MVC Entity Framework Check if Permission Is In Role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, oop

I have the following Model and I want a method to check if a permission is in a role. Currently I'm implementing this using the IsPermissionInRole method which does a for loop:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public ApplicationRole() : base() { }
    public ApplicationRole(string name) : base(name) { }

    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

    public bool IsPermissionInRole(string _permission)
    {
        bool _retVal = false;
        try
        {
            foreach (Permission _perm in Permissions)
            {
                if (_perm.Name == _permission)
                {
                    _retVal = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return _retVal;
    }

}
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this perhaps using some linq query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or simpler

```
 public bool IsPermissionInRole(string _permission)
 {
    return Permissions.Any(p => p.Name == _permission);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following using [`Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (Permissions.Any(p => p.Name == _permission))
{
    _retVal = true;
}
```